# rubyのopen-uriで403エラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

rubyのopen-uriを使って、あるサイト内のページ内容を読み込もうとしていますが、
403エラーになります（ブラウザからのアクセスは可能）。

```
url = "https://www.hogehoge.jp"
opt = {}
opt['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36'
opt['ssl_verify_mode'] = 'OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE'
opt['Accept-Encoding'] = 'deflate'
opt['Accept-Language'] = 'ja,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8'
page = open(url, opt).read
```

開発はcloud9、本番環境はawsのlightsailです。
開発中に403エラーが出た際、cloud9が海外IPのためではと考え、
国内の自前サーバにsquidを使ってproxyサーバを設置し、それを通してアクセスしたところ、
問題なく接続できました。

しかし、capistranoを使ってlightsailにデプロイしたところ、403エラーとなってしまいます。
lightsailの環境変数にも同じproxyを設定しています。

アプリの内容はもちろん、アクセス元のIPやhttpヘッダは同じはずなのに、
一方のみ403エラーとなり、原因が全く思いつきません。

よろしくお願いいたします。

【追記】
ブラウザの表示は、

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.
>   If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
>   のよく出るやつです。

production.logは、以下の通りです。

```
I, [2018-02-02T12:46:56.074182 #2970]  INFO -- : Started GET "/xxxx/getdata" for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2018-02-02 12:46:56 +0900
I, [2018-02-02T12:46:56.075338 #2970]  INFO -- : Processing by xxxxController#getdata as HTML
I, [2018-02-02T12:46:56.267191 #2970]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 192ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
F, [2018-02-02T12:46:56.267782 #2970] FATAL -- :
F, [2018-02-02T12:46:56.267829 #2970] FATAL -- : OpenURI::HTTPError (403 Forbidden):
F, [2018-02-02T12:46:56.267853 #2970] FATAL -- :
F, [2018-02-02T12:46:56.267881 #2970] FATAL -- : app/controllers/xxx_controller.rb:25:in `getdata'
```

【追記】
net/httpでの取得方法に変更したところ、コントローラに記載していると正常動作、遅延処理のためdelayed_jobで動作させようと、jobファイルに記載すると403エラーが出るようになりました。

```
parsed_url = URI.parse('https://www.hogehoge.jp')
https = Net::HTTP.new(parsed_url.host, parsed_url.port)
https.use_ssl = true
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(parsed_url.request_uri)
res = https.start do |x|
  x.request(req)
end
page = res.body.force_encoding("UTF-8")
```

【追記】
以下の方法でレスポンスヘッダとレスポンスボディを取得しました。
varnish cache serverがエラーを返しているようですが、原因がわかりません。

```
logger.error("*****response header*******")
res.each_header do | name, val |
  logger.error("name=#{name}, val=#{val}")
end

page = res.body.force_encoding("UTF-8")

logger.error("******page********")
logger.error(page)
```

結果

```
E, [2018-03-26T15:35:43.256675 #8988] ERROR -- : *****response code*******
E, [2018-03-26T15:35:43.256720 #8988] ERROR -- : 403
E, [2018-03-26T15:35:43.256742 #8988] ERROR -- : *****response header*******
E, [2018-03-26T15:35:43.256766 #8988] ERROR -- : name=server, val=Varnish
E, [2018-03-26T15:35:43.256785 #8988] ERROR -- : name=retry-after, val=0
E, [2018-03-26T15:35:43.256803 #8988] ERROR -- : name=content-type, val=text/html; charset=utf-8
E, [2018-03-26T15:35:43.256819 #8988] ERROR -- : name=content-length, val=421
E, [2018-03-26T15:35:43.256836 #8988] ERROR -- : name=accept-ranges, val=bytes
E, [2018-03-26T15:35:43.256857 #8988] ERROR -- : name=date, val=Mon, 26 Mar 2018 06:32:14 GMT
E, [2018-03-26T15:35:43.256876 #8988] ERROR -- : name=via, val=1.1 varnish
E, [2018-03-26T15:35:43.256893 #8988] ERROR -- : name=connection, val=close
E, [2018-03-26T15:35:43.256909 #8988] ERROR -- : name=x-served-by, val=cache-nrt6149-NRT
E, [2018-03-26T15:35:43.257132 #8988] ERROR -- : name=x-cache, val=MISS
E, [2018-03-26T15:35:43.257152 #8988] ERROR -- : name=x-cache-hits, val=0
E, [2018-03-26T15:35:43.257168 #8988] ERROR -- : name=x-timer, val=S1522045935.830867,VS0,VE0
E, [2018-03-26T15:35:43.257185 #8988] ERROR -- : ******page********
E, [2018-03-26T15:35:43.257201 #8988] ERROR -- :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>403 Forbidden</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Error 403 Forbidden</h1>
    <p>Forbidden</p>
    <h3>Guru Mediation:</h3>
    <p>Details: cache-nrt6149-NRT 1522045935 1982824828</p>
    <hr>
    <p>Varnish cache server</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: エラーの詳細の追記は可能でしょうか？ 403が返ってきた以外の情報に何かヒントがあるかもしれません。

Comment: @cul8er 編集で追記しました。

Comment: 本題とは関係ないと思うのでコメントにしますが、
`opt['ssl_verify_mode'] = 'OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE'` は
`opt[:ssl_verify_mode] = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE` の間違いでは?

Comment: @masm ありがとうございます。修正しました。

Answer (score 1):

何らかの理由で拒否されていますが、OpenURIでは例外発生時にレスポンスボディを取得できないので詳細はわかりません。プロキシなどのログにもレスポンスコードしか記載されないので同様です。

レスポンスボディに詳細が記載されている可能性がありますが、そのためにはOpenURIではなくnet/httpなどを使ったコードに書き換える必要があります。

サブステータスコードを確認、という回答がついていますが、IISの独自のものでログなどみてもわかりません。

Comment: @suzukisありがとうございます。ちょっと時間が開いてしまったのですが、net/httpを使って書き直してみました（コードは本文に追記）。
症状が変化し、コントローラに直接記載すると正常動作するようになりましたが、本来の目的であるdelayed_jobのjobファイルに記載すると403エラーを吐くようになりました。
 レスポンスボディの取得について、調べたものの、いまいちすっきりとわかりません。少しヒントをいただけないでしょうか。

Comment: 本文に追記した方法で、レスポンスヘッダとレスポンスボディを取得できました。ありがとうございます。Varnish cache serverが、delayed_jobの時のみ403を返しているようですが、原因がわかりません。

Answer (score 0):

エラーログにサブステータスコードが書かれていませんか？ログの中で"403"という文字列の近くを探してみてください。
[■ IISのステータスコードは小数点つきという話](http://subtech.g.hatena.ne.jp/mayuki/20131120/1384901536)　のページにログの例があるので参考にしてください。

403エラー(https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403)のサブステータスコードが判るとエラーの原因を絞り込めます。

Comment: production.logを見ましたが、それらしきものが見つかりません。（内容は追記しました）ブラウザに表示させられればよいのですが…。

Comment: webサーバーなどのログはどうですか？アクセスログとエラーログがあったような。(httpdの場合)

Comment: @cul8er nginxのログには403エラー自体が記録されていませんでした…。

Comment: open-uriを直接使っているので、もしrailsが動作している側のnginxのログを見たのだとしたら何も出ないですね。それはそうですね、すみません。squidを使ったことはないのですが、それがプロクシサーバーならそっちのログになにか残ってたりはしないのでしょうか??  勘違いだったらすみません。

Comment: @cul8er ありがとうございます。squidのログは、開発環境からのアクセス（エラーが出ない場合のみ）については記録されているのですが、エラーが出たものについては記録されていませんでした。